# Colimits of Lawvere theories

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra, limits-colimits

In Proposition 3.11.1 of Volume 2 of Borceux's Handbook of Categorical Algebra, he proves that the category of Lawvere theories is cocomplete, and his proof of this result uses the fact that every Lawvere theory has a syntactic presentation and every syntactic presentation of an algebraic theory has an associated Lawvere theory. Is there a more purely categorical (i.e. syntax-free) way to prove that the category of Lawvere theories is cocomplete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The category $\mathbf{Law}$ of Lawvere theories is algebraic, as described [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4189710). Every algebraic category is cocomplete (in fact, [locally (strongly) finitely presentable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+finitely+presentable+category)). This follows, for instance, from the theory of sketches. A good reference is Adámek–Rosický's [On sifted colimits and generalized varieties](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/8/n3/8-03abs.html).